# Set a dynamic Apple menu title for Java program in NetBeans 7.4

Tags: java, macos, netbeans-7

I inherited a Java app built (I believe) in Eclipse, which I'm modifying using NetBeans 7.4. I want to set the main menu title which shows up on a Mac next to the Apple menu. Right now that name is `MainForm`, but I want it to change dynamically to the contents of a specific text file (`name.txt`). I've looked up tons of info on project.properties, ANT scripts, and the like, but I can't find a definitive (and hopefully cross-platform) way to set this main menu title. I have a function in my code that returns this name, so I can use that if there's a place to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007512/how-can-i-change-my-java-swing-application-title-in-mac-os-x-title-bar

Comment: My two cents: there is no way to do this because the application name is not suppose to change.  You can set the title bar of a window, this can change, but the application name is intended to remain constant from the point of installation.  You can set it in Info.plist of an app bundle or Xdock:name -- there's no other way I'm aware of.

Comment: Since posting this, I've learned that I might have to create an executable in order to pass in this parameter. That would work fine; if it ends up being the answer, I'll post as such.

Answer (score 4):

I have found that in order to set the App Name in Mac OS X Application Menu, and avoid having it show up as the name of your Java project, you have to set it VERY early in the application cycle, using `System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.name", "Your App Name");`

Here's how I have mine set in my "main" java method that launches the application:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // the application menu for Mac OS X must be set very early in the cycle
    String opSysName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (opSysName.contains("mac")) {
        // to set the name of the app in the Mac App menu:
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.name", "Your App Name");
        //to show the menu bar at the top of the screen:
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        // to show a more mac-like file dialog box
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
        //underlying laf:
        javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();

        // other set-up code goes here
    }
    else {  // not on Mac OS X
        // set-up code for non-Mac systems
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        // run the program

    });

}
```